# 1D Boundary Conditions for Electrostatics

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, boundary-conditions

Consider a line of charge with charge density $\lambda$. Zoom in close enough such that the line charge density is constant.

1. How do we find the discontinuity in electric field across the line of charge?
2. How is the electric field of a static charge rigorously defined at the location of the static charge?

I followed Griffiths derivation for the discontinuity in electric field across a surface, but substituted the surface for a line of charge. In the surface case, the electric field due to the surface charge density $\sigma$ is constant. His derivation doesn't work for the line charge case because the electric field produced by a line of charge with constant $\lambda$ depends on $r^{-1}$, i.e. goes to infinity as we approach the line of charge.

I think the other boundary conditions can be found in the same manner as before:
$$\oint_LE\cdot dl=0 \text{ (condition of electrostatics  )}$$
$$\Phi_2 - \Phi_1 = 0\text{ }.$$

The first implies that the parallel components of electric field suffer no discontinuity. The second of which comes from the fact that no work is done as you cross the surface.

All help would be much appreciated!

Comment: This is a very natural question, that I think any good physicist ask himself, when he is taking electrostatics for first or second year. A quick answer, which might alleviate your worrysome is that electrodynamics don't work at small scales, so neither does electrostatics. There are discontinuities in the fields. And infinite selfs energies :(. But I hope someone with more time, can make you an answer that let's you more in peace.

Comment: If you think of these theories describing non punctual particles, but volume elements these problem don't arise that often, still in QED you have problems like those you have to renormalize, and we go to string theory where even the interactions are not computed in point like coordinates, but in lines or surfaces, to evade this discontiniuties, etc... This is outside my expertise, so don't take my words as absolute true, but keep in mind, that physics theories are not perfect even when they look beautiful and have problems and discontinuities